# SQL Server doesn't disable index

Tags: sql-server, resize, indexing

I have test database and im trying to resize column some column with index.
Table has few rows.
Let's not talk, let's show code

```
Create Table Country (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, NAME VARCHAR(48),ENEMY VARCHAR(32),AMOUNT INT);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_COUNTRY_NAME ON Country(NAME);
```

I add some rows. Later use sql sentences to resize column like this:

```
ALTER INDEX IDX_COUNTRY_NAME ON Country disable;

alter table COUNTRY alter column NAME VARCHAR(40);

ALTER INDEX IDX_COUNTRY_NAME ON Country rebuild;`
```

And this is what i got after trying to update column

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The index 'IDX_COUNTRY_NAME' is dependent on column 'NAME'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeBatch(JtdsStatement.java:947)
    at com.veraxsystems.commons.updater.tasks.ResizeColumnTask.execute(ResizeColumnTask.java:52)
    at com.veraxsystems.commons.updater.tasks.AbstractTask.process(AbstractTask.java:79)
    at com.veraxsystems.commons.Updater.executeUpdate(Updater.java:169)
    at com.veraxsystems.commons.Updater.afterPropertiesSet(Updater.java:201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I want to avoid droping indexes because i dont know if scripts to random indexes in future exists and i would have problem to reload them.
Im using sql server 2008
I tried a lot of ways to finish this. Only hope was to use drop, but as i said before, i would prefer not to use it.

**EDIT**

These are just example sql, i know which table and column i update. To find it i use sys.indexes, sys.index_columns and join them by object_id. This works fine cause i printed all result and was like expected.

Comment: "i dont know if scripts to random indexes in future exists" - how would you're proposed solution get around this - you still had to know the index to disable it... Anyhow, I believe the index *is* disabled, but the disabled index still doesn't allow the schema modification to occur.

Comment: To find all index in table for column i join sys.indexes and sys.index_columns by object_id, because i know object_id and column_id so its easy to know what index i will find. I just try not to drop them (first collect all data about them) and create, but only disable/rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) on ALTER TABLE, the ALTER COLUMN section:

> The modified column cannot be any one of the following:
>
> […]
>
> - Used in an index, unless the column is a varchar, nvarchar, or varbinary data type, the data type is not changed, *the new size is **equal to or larger** than the old size*, and the index is not the result of a PRIMARY KEY constraint.
>
> […]

(Italics and emphasis are mine.)

You are trying to decrease the size of an indexed column (from (`varchar(48)` to `varchar(40)`), which is "against the rules". Seems like there's no other option apart from dropping/recreating the index.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are totally right.
It looks like i have to re-read a lot of things again :)